read_csv drops 'f' from end of string
I am importing a csv with read_csv. The data looks like:
x <- rep("1306f",5)
y <- sample(1:10, 5)
df <- cbind(x,y)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
write.csv(df, "Desktop/names_test.csv")

When I import this using temp<-read_csv("Desktop/names_test.csv") the first column is only '1306'. When I import using temp<-read.csv("Desktop/names_test.csv) I get '1306f' as expected.
If the last letter is not the same in each row like this:
x <- c("1306c","1306d","1306e","1306f","1306g")
y <- sample(1:10, 5)
df <- cbind(x,y)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
write.csv(df, "Desktop/names_test.csv")

I get the expected values in the first column when importing using read_csv, including the 'f'. This only happens with that letter (i.e. if the last letter is always c I get the expected).
Any thoughts? I can obviously just use read.csv, but hoping to stay with the tidyverse.

I can't reproduce that.  Also as an aside, note that cbind(x,y) is a character matrix and so df has two character columns.  Use df <- data.frame(x, y)

You can tell read_csv to treat that column as a character value: read_csv("Desktop/names_test.csv", col_types =cols(x=col_character()))

I can reproduce this. I'm using R 4.4.0 on Windows 11, readr 2.1.5.

I reproduced  the issue ; (however I change utils::write.csv() for  reader::write_csv() to avoid delimiters issues since my locale is in french). I am curious  about this behaviour. The main element is probably that read_csv() detect the column as double.

I get the same issue with "1305L" - converts to numeric. R would interpret L as an integer indicator, so I'm wondering if f is also an indicator of something (perhaps a float indicator in a Cpp module somewhere in readr)??

This seems very close to my recent question about converting strings like "XXXe"    ;    see   https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2024-May/479282.html

Gee, you really found something, I was (also) not aware of or come across. @MrFlick showed already how to coerce the read in data to a character (and then take it from there). Often forgotten is the str() function that can sometimes give you a hint ...
If you run read_csv("Desktop/names_test.csv") |> str()  and readr::read_csv("Desktop/names_test.csv") |> str() you will also see that the read in data types of the columns is interpreted differently. So ... yes ... I guess this is a feature!

The suggestion from @MrFlick worked to solve this issue.

I just had this same issue. I was reading in a series of files in a loop, like so:
df = read_csv(paste0(getwd(),"/",i))
  if(ind==1){df2 = df}
  if(ind>1){df2 = rbind(df2,df)}}

where the files contain cells that have data like, "2A", "2B", ... "2F", in a column. When cells that end in either, F, L, or S were read, it dropped the letter and just returned the number before it, resulting in something like:
"3A", "3B", "3C", "3D", "3E", "3", "3G".
Adding in col_types = cols(UNIT=col_character()) fixes the issue.

readr is guessing the column should be a character type, so the solution is to be more explicit about what the column type should be. There are quite a few ways to do this depending on what you need, and I'd suggest looking at the read_csv() help page and the cols() help page
x <- rep("1306f",5)
y <- sample(1:10, 5)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
write.csv(df, "names_test.csv")

library(readr)
simple <- read_csv("names_test.csv")
#> New names:
#> Rows: 5 Columns: 3
#> ── Column specification
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────── Delimiter: "," dbl
#> (3): ...1, x, y
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data. ℹ
#> Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> • `` -> `...1`
# readr is 'guessing' the column should be a double
spec(simple)
#> cols(
#>   ...1 = col_double(),
#>   x = col_double(),
#>   y = col_double()
#> )

explicit <- read_csv("names_test.csv", col_types = cols(x = col_character()))
#> New names:
#> • `` -> `...1`
spec(explicit)
#> cols(
#>   ...1 = col_double(),
#>   x = col_character(),
#>   y = col_double()
#> )
explicit
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>    ...1 x         y
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1 1306f     5
#> 2     2 1306f     8
#> 3     3 1306f    10
#> 4     4 1306f     2
#> 5     5 1306f     4

Created on 2024-07-02 with reprex v2.1.0
